# How to get all of the values instead of getting the first index in java?

Tags: java

I am coming to an issue is when I get the term of any value I get from my results (shown below), The results does not show all of my rest array objects that is shown like my schema below. Can any one help me to show like my custom schema below? I am just getting the first index instead of three values of mine. thanks for the help.

Comment: It is very unclear what exactly it is you are asking.

Comment: @Alan Hay . to return like my schema above. That is the way I want to accomplish. Let me know if you dont understand my issue.

Comment: This is the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56755855/how-to-return-only-an-one-instance-in-java/ (particularly the original post). Although it was never answered perhaps some of the comments there will help you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand the question exactly.

But if you want to have all results instead of just one, you have to return the list of results. Actually you return only the first element.

The line

```
return autoCompleteService.retrieveSalary(autocompleteValue).get(0);
```

Should be :

```
return autoCompleteService.retrieveSalary(autocompleteValue);
```

Comment: I know that way. But, I am not looking to return like that. Can you please see my code above where I posted my schema under: "Schema (What I want to accomplish)" . That is the way I want to show my `rateTypes`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please add more details? If hourly, weekly and annual are not directly mapped to a column in your entity(I do not see them in the code above, so assuming they are not) and need to be calculated based on other values in the entity object, you would include @transient annotation in a method that gets these calculated values.

```
   @transient
    int getHourly(){
    // Logic to calculate hourly salary
    }
    @transient
    int getWeekly(){
    // Logic to calculate weekly salary
    }
```

Comment: hmmm... I dont think this is the way I want to accomplish. Have you checked my code above under: "Schema (What I want to accomplish)"?  That is the way I want to accomplish. List of arrays like that. Right now it just gets the first index.

Comment: Could you please explain the relationship between AutoComplete and annual/weekly/hourly? Is it one-to-one? Are those represented by rate_type column?

Comment: Will each AutoComplete ( this represents a Job?) have 1 hourly, 1 weekly and 1 annual attribute?

Comment: correct. yes the same with the annual .  that is getting my first index.

Comment: `@transient
    List<String> getHourly(){
 String hourlySalary = // Logic to calculate hourly salary based on rate type
 return Arrays.asList(hourlySalary);
    }
    @transient
    List<String> getWeekly(){
 String weeklySalary = // Logic to calculate weekly salary
 return Arrays.asList(weeklySalary); 
    } `

Comment: where to implement this? in controller? can you please show me a working code of mines - if possible?

Comment: Try the above. It is formatted weirdly, but am sure you get the point

Comment: In your entity. AutoComplete class. You do not want the convenience logic in a controller. This should be in Entity, in your case. that way any new service will get data is the same scheme.

Comment: I imported `@Transient`.  can you please provide a working code?

Comment: You are right, it is @Transient not @transient.  ` @javax.persistence.Transient
    public List<String> getWeekly(){
        String weeklySalary = null; // Logic to calculate weekly salary
        return Arrays.asList(weeklySalary);
    } `

Comment: where to use `getHourly()` and `getWeekly()` methods?

Comment: Same place (AutoComplete class) I gave getWeekly as example. Rest will be similar and placed in same class.

Comment: and my controller. Should I leave `return autoCompleteService.retrieveSalary(autocompleteValue).get(0);` ?

Comment: I think you have 2 different problems. Your controller should have ` autoCompleteService.retrieveSalary(autocompleteValue); ` as the other commentor mentioned. The return type of your controller will now be a List that represents all AutoComplete entities that match a job code.  Each AutoComplete in the response will have one weekly, onle hourly and 1 annual salary (although represented as list, as that is the schema you desire)

Comment: Btw, can you share your AutoCompleteSerailizer code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195585/discussion-between-mike-and-vanitha-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

Based on chat conversation, the right thing to do will be to normalize your database table. If that is not a choice, you can transform result set using Java Streams.  [Similar example using Streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44540040/java-8-stream-merge-collections-of-objects-sharing-the-same-id)

Unable to provide working code based on snippets alone.