# Java 8 Group By one parameter and obtain a list of objects as result

Tags: java, java-8

I have a User object like this:

```
class User{
   int id;
   String name;
   List<String> subject;
}
```

```java
class Main {

    public static void main (str args[]) {
    
       List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();
    
       User user1 = new User(1, "John", Arrays.asList("English"));
       User user2 = new User(2,"Peter", Arrays.asList("English"));
       user user3 = new User(1, "John", Arrays.asList("Chemistry"));
    
       userList.add(user1); userList.add(user2); userList.add(user3);
    }
}
```

I want to group by id and get the entire `User` object as a response `Map<Integer, List<User>>` like:

```
User1 = (1, "John", {"English","Chemistry"});
User2 = (2, "Peter", {"English"});
```

How do we map and get the entire object?

Comment: sorry its updated

Comment: Ah. Then `userList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(User::getId))` should work for you (assumes an appropriate `getId()` method declared in `User`).

Comment: Subject should be aggregated/appended in the same user1 record

Comment: But `subject` is not a list. `List<User>` is.

Comment: That sounds like what you really want is a `Map<Integer, User>` and change `subject` to be a `List<String>`. And what happens if two users with the same ID have different names? Or is that not possible?

Comment: User obj is updated now

Comment: So is your actual goal to make a map or are you wanting to merge the `subject` list for user objects that share the same id? If the latter, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44540040/java-8-stream-merge-collections-of-objects-sharing-the-same-id) may prove helpful.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the `toMap` collector and provide a mergeFunction.
`Collectors.toMap()` can be called with 3 parameters: first one is for mapping they key of the map, in our case the user id, so something like this `user -> user.getId()` or simply `User::getId`.

The second parameter is mapping the value, in our case we want to use the user itself as value, so we'll just pass `user -> user`.

Finally, the merge functions will be used for users this the same id (duplicates): in this case we want to create a new User that has all the subjects:

```
private User mergeUsers(User user1, User user2) {
    List<String> allSubjects = new ArrayList<>();
    allSubjects.addAll(user1.getSubject());
    allSubjects.addAll(user2.getSubject());
    return new User(user1.getId(), user1.getName(), allSubjects);
}
```

Now, let's stream the users and collect them as discussed:

```
@Test
void test2() {
    //given
    User user1 = new User(1, "John", Arrays.asList("English"));
    User user2 = new User(2,"Peter", Arrays.asList("English"));
    User user3 = new User(1, "John", Arrays.asList("Chemistry"));
    List<User> users = List.of(user1, user2, user3);

    //when
    Map<Integer, User> usersById = users.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(u-> u.getId(), u -> u, (u1, u2) -> mergeUsers(u1, u2)));

    //then
    assertThat(usersById.get(1).getSubject())
            .containsExactly("English", "Chemistry");
    assertThat(usersById.get(2).getSubject())
            .containsExactly("English");
}
```

ps: you can make small improvements, such as using method reference or encapsulating this logic of merging inside the User class:

```
Map<Integer, User> usersById = users.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(User::getId, user -> user, User::merge));
```

read more about Colelctors.toMap and mergingFunction here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-collectors-tomap

Answer (score -1):

```
HashMap<Integer, User> users = new HashMap<Integer, User>();
users.put(1,new User(1, "John", Arrays.asList("English")));
users.put(2,new User(2, "Peter", Arrays.asList("English")));
users.put(3,new User(3, "John", Arrays.asList("English")));
```

This will get record corresponding to userId but userId has to be unique.